# ConcatAdapter how to change scroll position of inner RecyclerView that is located in an Adapter from another Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, android-concatadapter

[image]

In the image section with Favorites and the horizontal RecyclerView is one adapter, **adapterFavoriteProperties**,  while the row
with chart is another adapter, **adapterChart**, of the main RecyclerView. Main RecyclerView is composed of rows that coming each from different adapter that is glued with Concat Adapter.

```
val concatAdapter =
        ConcatAdapter(
            adapterFavoriteProperties,
            adapterChart,
            adapterMostViewedProperties,
            adapterRecommendedProperties
        )
```

Also adapter for chart has a lambda available in the fragment

```
    val chartItemClickLambda: ((Float) -> Unit) = { position ->
        println(" DashboardFragment chart CLICK $position")

    }

    val adapterChart =
        ChartContainerAdapter(chartItemClickLambda)
```

The section that contains title, see All and recyclerView is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="propertyListModel"
            type="com.smarttoolfactory.dashboard.model.PropertyItemListModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        visibilityBasedOn="@{!propertyListModel.items.isEmpty()}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@{propertyListModel.title}"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Title" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSeeAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            visibilityBasedOn="@{propertyListModel.seeAll}"
            android:text="See all"
            android:textColor="#FB8C00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="See all" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            app:items="@{propertyListModel.items}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

And it's adapter

```
class HorizontalListWithTitleAdapter(
    private val onItemClick: ((PropertyItem) -> Unit)? = null
) :
    ListAdapter<PropertyItemListModel, HorizontalItemViewHolder>(
        DefaultItemDiffCallback()
    ) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HorizontalItemViewHolder {

        return HorizontalItemViewHolder(
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.layout_list_with_title,
                parent, false
            ),
            onItemClick
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HorizontalItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindTo(currentList[position])
    }
}
```

and `ViewHolder`

```
class HorizontalItemViewHolder(
    private val binding: LayoutListWithTitleBinding,
    private val onItemClick: ((PropertyItem) -> Unit)? = null
) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bindTo(item: PropertyItemListModel) {

        binding.setVariable(BR.propertyListModel, item)

        binding.recyclerView.apply {

            // Set Layout manager
            this.layoutManager =
                ScaledLinearLayoutManager(this.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

            // Set RecyclerViewAdapter
            val itemListAdapter = PropertyListAdapter(R.layout.item_property_favorite, onItemClick)

            this.adapter = itemListAdapter

        }

        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

This where i should have either reference of RecyclerView or have ViewHolder to call it's recyclerView's `smoothScrollToPosition(position)`